# Azure Machine Learning - Use personal container registry

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-machine-learning-service

I tried to run this code to create an ml workspace from the azure-ml-cli, referencing an existing azure container registry from another subscription:

```
az ml workspace create --workspace-name "test-mlws" --keyvault "<key-vault-service-id>" --container-registry "<container-registry-zervice-id>" --location westeurope
```

The deploy failed with this error code:

```
{'code': 'InternalServerError', 'message': 'Received 403 from a service request'}
```

I can't find any documentation about it, and I guess it's due to the container registry I used which belongs to another subscription. Anyone who knows if it's mandatory for the registry to be in the same subscription?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-manage-workspace?tabs=python#limitations

> If you want to use **existing services from a different Azure
> subscription** than the workspace, you must register the Azure Machine
> Learning namespace in the subscription that contains those services.

So, in order to use the ACR in that different subscription, you need to register resource provider `Microsoft.MachineLearningServices` in that subscription contains ACR. For information on how to see if it is registered and how to register it, see the [Azure resource providers and types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/resource-providers-and-types) article.

To register a resource provider, use:

```
Register-AzResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.MachineLearningServices
```

To see information for a particular resource provider, use:

```
Get-AzResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.MachineLearningServices
```